# AWS Free tier: Step Function: cannot be created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have created a new AWS free accpunt to have a possibility to test Step functions.

Then go to Step Functions, get Started, I see the simple Hello World function. But when click Next - it does nothing, no errors but it stay on this page. What I do wrong ? How to create a Step Function at least Hello World suggested by AWS?

Comment: It sounds like an error in the browser. Please quit & restart the browser, or try a different browser. If it persists, you can view the browser's developer console to see error messages.